# What is the need to subclass a UIView instead of creating our own view and adding it to

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

Why would anyone subclass a UIView instead of creating our own custom view like this:

```
CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(20,20,20,20); //Frame to contain the current view
UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
label.text = @”This is a custom view with out subclassing UIView”
[self.view addSubView:label];
```

Is don't see any tradeoffs or advantages? Am I missing something?

Comment: A UILabel is a subclass of a UIView, so it is kind of self explanatory why you would use a UILabel instead of a UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a lot of cases where you are just rearranging text, and utilizing some of the built in buttons, labels, etc; it is not necessary to subclass a `UIView` and can instead be done programmatically through a `UIViewController` or added to a storyboard/nib file. However, a great example of when and why you would want to subclass a `UIView` is if you wanted to add some custom touch behavior or drawing to the view that you are using.

So the way I see it, the main considerations in subclassing a `UIView` comes down to the following:

1) Touch interaction,

2) Custom Drawing

*Note that there may be other reasons you may want to create a view subclass simply from a program organization perspective, but these are the main three that the behavior cannot be delegate to another function, or added directly to the `UIView`. For example, support for general animations and background image manipulation can all be handled without subclassing `UIView`.

**Touch Interaction** - Touch interaction with a `UIView` can be handled in a couple different ways, you can interact directly with the touch events, or add a gesture recognizer to the `UIView`. In many cases, you can accomplish everything that you need to through a gesture recognizer (or custom gesture recognizer), rather than attempting to look at the individual touches that are occurring on your view, but if you wanted/needed to access the raw touch events, you would override the following functions to implement the desired behavior:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

**Custom Drawing** - In a `UIView` you can do basic 2D drawing through Quartz/Core Graphics. One example is that if you were doing a graphing application and wanted your `UIView` to draw the actual lines for you within its context on the screed. To accomplish this, you would override the `drawRect:(CGRect)rect`  function and list any custom drawing here.

That being said, this is by no means the only way that you could draw a line, and could complete this task without performing custom drawing. For example, that same line, or set of lines, could be drawn into an image buffer by your `UIViewController`, and then displayed as the background of your view or a subview accordingly. When doing that however, the `UIView` loses the knowledge of the line on screen, and touch interaction directly with that line becomes more challenging. In the end, keep in mind that there are creative ways to get around subclassing just to display custom drawing, but sometimes from a program design perspective it may make more sense to just create a `UIView` subclass.

These are by no means the only reasons that you would want to subclass a `UIView`, but have been the 2 biggest reasons that I have seen used for creating a subclass of `UIView`. I would suggest that you look at [UIView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) or [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

for the same reason UIView is subclassed with controls and text layout views in UIKit: because the existing implementations don't do *everything*, and custom implementation or members are needed (at times).

however, you might subclass UILabel in this case, if you needed to do something specific, or reuse an implementation and subclassing were a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would say custom behaviors and custom layouts. Handling resizing beyond what is available to auto-resizing mask or smart loading subviews is more difficult to do from an outside controller.

I've created a custom image view that has a scroll view to see a long list of images in a three column display. It internally manages the images, so it only loads views for images that are seen on the screen.

Could you imagine having to build a UITableView by hand compositing the scroll view with cells, managing the queue of cell views, having to smart load the cells only when they would appear, and handling all the tap, swipe, and pan gestures every time you needed a screen with a tabular look?